# CUDA development Mac Mini

Tags: macos, cuda

I'm very new in CUDA development and I don't know how to start. I have a Mac Mini [image]

With a OS X 10.8.3 and XCode 4.6.3. Can I use it for CUDA development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to use CUDA, as you do not have an NVidia graphics card. You might want to look into [OpenCL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk) which is supported on Intel CPUs and GPUs (as well as AMD and NVidia GPUs). OpenCL is similar to the CUDA Driver API and therefore what you learn programming in OpenCL will help with learning CUDA as well since many of the concepts are similar.

For OpenCL on Mac, check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do CUDA development on **some** Mac Minis.

You, of course, need a model with an Nvidia GPU.  I'm doing it on my 2010 Mini which has a NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB.  This is a lightweight chip.  It only has 48 CUDA cores, but it is good for educational use.

You can get info on the software you need here:
https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa12/cse260-b/RoomFullOfMacMinis.txt